# CrossWalkのarm64-v8a対応に関して

Tags: android, monaca, cordova

いつもお世話になっております。

CordovaとCrossWalkを用いてツールアプリを開発しております。

今年2015年夏モデルのXperiaZ4やGalaxyS6_Edgがarm64-v8aだと知ったのですが、CrossWalkのHPから「Cordova Android」の[Stable]をDLしたところ、libsフォルダ内にはarmeabi-v7aに対応したsoファイルしかありませんでした。

CrossWalkを扱った方で、XperiaZ4やGalaxyS6_Edgなどのarm64-v8aに対応させた方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示のほどよろしくお願いいたします。